# How to disable y-axis in mosaic plot?

Tags: r

How to disable **y-axis** in mosaic plot?

Example:

```
x <- data.frame(o=c(rep("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",50),rep("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",40),rep("CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",70)),r=runif(160))
x$int <- findInterval(x$r, seq(0.1,1,0.1), rightmost.closed = TRUE, all.inside = TRUE)

tab.dat <- with(x, table(o, int))

par(mar=c(3, 3, 3, 3))
mosaicplot(tab.dat, col=colorRampPalette( c("green3", "yellow", "red"), space="rgb")(9), las=2, dir=c("h","v"))
```

I would like to use own axis function. So how can I remove the y axis names? Usually something like `yaxt="n"` works, but not it this case.

```
axis(2, at=seq(0, 1, by = 1 / (length(rownames(tab.dat)) - 1)), labels=rownames(tab.dat), cex.axis=2.2, line=1.1, las=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it directly from the `mosaicplot` function but there is an easy alternative.

Just turn the `tab.dat` row names to `''` and this will work fine

```
tab.dat <- with(x, table(o, int))

#I am only adding this line of code below
#just use the row.names function to set the names to ''
row.names(tab.dat) <- rep('',3)

par(mar=c(3, 3, 3, 3))
mosaicplot(tab.dat, col=colorRampPalette( c("green3", "yellow", "red"), space="rgb")(9), las=2, dir=c("h","v") )
```

Seems like an easy to do hack. Maybe this is why the developers didn't include it as an argument in `mosaicplot`.

Output:

[image]